# Why my using memo didn't raise the efficiency at all?

Tags: python, performance, memoization

I am doing exercise in Think in Python, using Memo to calculate Fibonacci sequence is far more efficiency than not using one. But when implemented it and testing the time consumed, I find the running time is not reduced at all. I know there are certainly something wrong with my program, could someone please tell me where I went wrong. Many thanks.

```
import time

known = {0:0,1:1}
def fibonacci_memo(n):
    """return the nth number of fibonacci sequence
    using memo to raise efficiency"""
    if n in known:
        return known[n]

    res = fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)
    known[n] = res
    return res

def fibonacci(n):
    """return the nth number of fibonacci sequence
    without using memo"""
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.clock()
    print fibonacci_memo(32)
    elaspsed = time.clock() - start
    print 'using memo time used: ' + str(elaspsed)

    start = time.clock()
    print fibonacci(32)
    elaspsed = time.clock() - start
    print 'without using memo time used: ' + str(elaspsed)
```

The Output is something like:

```
2178309
using memo time used: 1.83040345779
2178309
without using memo time used: 1.792043347
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your fibonacci_memo function isn't calling itself recursively, it's calling the original (non-memoized) fibonacci function.

Answer (score 2):

The recursion of your memoized function is calling a different function. Try replacing fibonacci_memo with this:

```
def fibonacci_memo(n):
    """return the nth number of fibonacci sequence
    using memo to raise efficiency"""
    if n in known:
        return known[n]

    res = fibonacci_memo(n-1) + fibonacci_memo(n-2)
    known[n] = res
    return res
```